# BottomNavigationBar - how to change the colour

Tags: android, background-color, android-bottomnav

The source of this component is :
https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

I have a bottom navigation bar in an Android App with 4 tabs on.

I want to set the background colour to be the same regardless of selected tab
I want to show icon + text for all tab buttons regardless of whether they are selected or not.

The background colour defaults to White. The only way I can find to change it is to call `setActiveTabColor()` for each Tab. This works but seems like overkill I should only need to set it in one place.

However the real problem is as follows :

I cannot show the text for all icons unless I call `useFixedMode();`

However once `useFixedMode()` is called, **SetActiveTabColor** no longer works and the I cannot then set the background colour - it defaults to white.

I have also tried `SetBackgroundColor();` to no effect

What am I missing ?

Comment: try this thread [https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar/issues/5](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar/issues/5)

Comment: Thanks for this link.